# Owl Carousel failing to load

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel

I'm trying to integrate Owl Carousel into a bootstrap site I'm making for a friend but I can't seem to get it to load. I get an error that mentions that .owlCarousel is not a function when I check out in Firebug.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
<div class="container"> <a id="gallery"></a>
  <div class="row-fluid PageHead">
    <div class="span12">
      <h3>IMAGE GALLERY<span> <img src="images/underline.png" alt="______"></span></h3>
    </div>
  </div>


    <div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel">
    <div class="item"><img class="lazyOwl" data-src="images/bandphotos/DSCN0224.JPG" alt="Lazy Owl Image"></div>
    <div class="item"><img class="lazyOwl" data-src="assets/owl2.jpg" alt="Lazy Owl Image"></div>
    <div class="item"><img class="lazyOwl" data-src="assets/owl3.jpg" alt="Lazy Owl Image"></div>
    <div class="item"><img class="lazyOwl" data-src="assets/owl4.jpg" alt="Lazy Owl Image"></div>
    <div class="item"><img class="lazyOwl" data-src="assets/owl5.jpg" alt="Lazy Owl Image"></div>
    <div class="item"><img class="lazyOwl" data-src="assets/owl6.jpg" alt="Lazy Owl Image"></div>
    <div class="item"><img class="lazyOwl" data-src="assets/owl7.jpg" alt="Lazy Owl Image"></div>
    <div class="item"><img class="lazyOwl" data-src="assets/owl8.jpg" alt="Lazy Owl Image"></div>
    <div class="item"><img class="lazyOwl" data-src="assets/owl1.jpg" alt="Lazy Owl Image"></div>
    <div class="item"><img class="lazyOwl" data-src="assets/owl2.jpg" alt="Lazy Owl Image"></div>
    <div class="item"><img class="lazyOwl" data-src="assets/owl3.jpg" alt="Lazy Owl Image"></div>
    <div class="item"><img class="lazyOwl" data-src="assets/owl4.jpg" alt="Lazy Owl Image"></div>
    <div class="item"><img class="lazyOwl" data-src="assets/owl5.jpg" alt="Lazy Owl Image"></div>
    <div class="item"><img class="lazyOwl" data-src="assets/owl6.jpg" alt="Lazy Owl Image"></div>
    <div class="item"><img class="lazyOwl" data-src="assets/owl7.jpg" alt="Lazy Owl Image"></div>
    <div class="item"><img class="lazyOwl" data-src="assets/owl8.jpg" alt="Lazy Owl Image"></div>
    </div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
    items : 4,
    lazyLoad : true,
    navigation : true
    });

    });

</script>

</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have not included the Owl code, or perhaps something that it depends on.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, it looks like you haven't actually added the .js file for this? You're just calling the function

Comment: Sorry I forgot I add that I added the following to the top of my index.html:

<!-- Important Owl stylesheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css">
     
<!-- Default Theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="owl-carousel/owl.theme.css">
     
<!-- Include js plugin -->
<script src="assets/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>

Answer (score 1):

Add this css in your `<head>` part.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="owlcarousel/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="owlcarousel/owl.theme.default.min.css">
```

Add this JS in above `</body>`

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="owlcarousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
```

Add this class in `<img>`

```
<div class="item"><img class="owl-lazy" data-src="assets/owl2.jpg" alt="Lazy Owl Image"></div>
```

Have Fun..!!

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your footer and double-check the path:

```
<script src="assets/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
```